# Parsing xml in perl

Tags: xml, perl, parsing

I want to parse this xml using Perl. The XML that I have shown here is only a part of much larger and nested XML. I have tried using normal parser and most of them give output in hash format which is difficult to read and access child nodes.

I want to fetch  elements and read all attribute values.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<TR name="App.exe" total="573" errors="1" failures="2" not-run="4" inconclusive="2" ignored="4" skipped="0" invalid="0" date="2015-01-12" time="17:43:59">
  <environment version="2" cversion="44" os-version="Microsoft" platform="Win32NT" cwd="" machine-name="" user="me" user-domain="domain" />
  <culture-info current-culture="en-US" current-uiculture="en-US" />
  <TS type="Assembly" name="App.exe" executed="True" result="Failure" success="False" time="22" asserts="0">
    <RS>
      <TS type="Namespace" name="MyAPP" executed="True" result="Failure" success="False" time="2335.164" asserts="0">
        <RS>
          <TS type="Namespace" name="Project" executed="True" result="Failure" success="False" time="2335.164" asserts="0">
            <RS>
              <TS type="Namespace" name="Website" executed="True" result="Failure" success="False" time="2335.164" asserts="0">
                <RS>
                  <TS type="Namespace" name="Service" executed="True" result="Failure" success="False" time="2335.163" asserts="0">
                    <RS>
                      <TS type="SetUpFixture" name="Tests" executed="True" result="Failure" success="False" time="2335.163" asserts="0">
                        <RS>
                          <TS type="Namespace" name="tempt" executed="True" result="Success" success="True" time="8.935" asserts="0">
                            <RS>
                              <TS type="ParameterizedFixture" name="TempAPI" executed="True" result="Success" success="True" time="8.935" asserts="0">
                                <RS>
                                  <TS type="TestFixture" name="Admin" executed="True" result="Success" success="True" time="3.306" asserts="2">
                                    <RS>
                                      <TC name="testName1" executed="True" result="Success" success="True" time="0.352" asserts="0" />
                                      <TC name="testName2" executed="True" result="Success" success="True" time="0.005" asserts="0" />
                                    </RS>
                                  </TS>
                                  <TS type="TestFixture" name="Client" executed="True" result="Success" success="True" time="2.620" asserts="1">
                                    <RS>
                                      <TC name="testName3" executed="True" result="Success" success="True" time="0.319" asserts="0" />
                                      <TC name="testName4" executed="True" result="Success" success="True" time="0.000" asserts="0" />
                                    </RS>
                                  </TS>
                                  <TS type="TestFixture" name="Employee" executed="True" result="Success" success="True" time="3.007" asserts="1">
                                    <RS>
                                      <TC name="testName5" executed="True" result="Success" success="True" time="0.290" asserts="0" />
                                      <TC name="testName6" executed="True" result="Success" success="True" time="0.000" asserts="0" />
                                    </RS>
                                  </TS>
                                </RS>
                              </TS>
                            </RS>
                          </TS>
                        </RS>
                      </TS>
                    </RS>
                  </TS>
                </RS>
              </TS>
            </RS>
          </TS>
        </RS>
      </TS>
    </RS>
  </TS>
</TR>
```

I tried doing this, which as I have said will give hash output which is difficult to read and fetch details.

```
my $list = XMLin('F:\Sample.xml', KeepRoot => 1);

#print $list-->{TS}[0]{name};
print Dumper($list );
write_file 'F:\mydump.log', Dumper($list);
```

I need suggestions about a parser that could output easily readable format than a hash.

With this XML::Simple I get this below format

```
$VAR1 = {
          'TR' => {
                  'failures' => '2',
                  'TS' => {
                          'asserts' => '0',
                          'success' => 'False',
                          'time' => '22',
                          'name' => 'App.exe',
                          'executed' => 'True',
                          'type' => 'Assembly',
                          'RS' => {
                                  'TS' => {
                                          'asserts' => '0',
                                          'success' => 'False',
                                          'time' => '2335.164',
                                          'name' => 'MyAPP',
                                          'executed' => 'True',
                                          'type' => 'Namespace',
                                          'RS' => {
                                                  'TS' => {
                                                          'asserts' => '0',
                                                          'success' => 'False',
                                                          'time' => '2335.164',
                                                          'name' => 'Project',
                                                          'executed' => 'True',
                                                          'type' => 'Namespace',
                                                          'RS' => {
                                                                  'TS' => {
                                                                          'asserts' => '0',
                                                                          'success' => 'False',
                                                                          'time' => '2335.164',
                                                                          'name' => 'Web',
                                                                          'executed' => 'True',
                                                                          'type' => 'Namespace',
                                                                          'RS' => {
                                                                                  'TS' => {
                                                                                          'asserts' => '0',
                                                                                          'success' => 'False',
                                                                                          'time' => '2335.163',
                                                                                          'name' => 'Server',
                                                                                          'executed' => 'True',
                                                                                          'type' => 'Namespace',
                                                                                          'RS' => {
                                                                                                  'TS' => {
                                                                                                          'asserts' => '0',
                                                                                                          'success' => 'False',
                                                                                                          'time' => '2335.163',
                                                                                                          'name' => 'Tests',

                                                                                                                                                          'Client' => {
                                                                                                                                                                      'success' => 'True',
                                                                                                                                                                      'asserts' => '1',
                                                                                                                                                                      'time' => '2.620',
                                                                                                                                                                      'executed' => 'True',
                                                                                                                                                                      'type' => 'TestFixture',
                                                                                                                                                                      'RS' => {
                                                                                                                                                                              'TC' => {
                                                                                                                                                                                      'testName3' => {
                                                                                                                                                                                                     'success' => 'True',
                                                                                                                                                                                                     'asserts' => '0',
                                                                                                                                                                                                     'time' => '0.319',
                                                                                                                                                                                                     'executed' => 'True',
                                                                                                                                                                                                     'result' => 'Success'
                                                                                                                                                                                                   },
                                                                                                                                                                                      'testName4' => {
                                                                                                                                                                                                     'success' => 'True',
                                                                                                                                                                                                     'asserts' => '0',
                                                                                                                                                                                                     'time' => '0.000',
                                                                                                                                                                                                     'executed' => 'True',
                                                                                                                                                                                                     'result' => 'Success'
                                                                                                                                                                                                   }
                                                                                                                                                                                    }
                                                                                                                                                                            },
                                                                                                                                                                      'result' => 'Success'
                                                                                                                                                                    },
                                                                                                                                                          'Admin' => {
                                                                                                                                                                     'success' => 'True',
                                                                                                                                                                     'asserts' => '2',
                                                                                                                                                                     'time' => '3.306',
                                                                                                                                                                     'executed' => 'True',
                                                                                                                                                                     'type' => 'TestFixture',
                                                                                                                                                                     'RS' => {
                                                                                                                                                                             'TC' => {
                                                                                                                                                                                     'testName1' => {
                                                                                                                                                                                                    'success' => 'True',
                                                                                                                                                                                                    'asserts' => '0',
                                                                                                                                                                                                    'time' => '0.352',
                                                                                                                                                                                                    'executed' => 'True',
                                                                                                                                                                                                    'result' => 'Success'
                                                                                                                                                                                                  },
                                                                                                                                                                                     'testName2' => {
                                                                                                                                                                                                    'success' => 'True',
                                                                                                                                                                                                    'asserts' => '0',
                                                                                                                                                                                                    'time' => '0.005',
                                                                                                                                                                                                    'executed' => 'True',
                                                                                                                                                                                                    'result' => 'Success'
                                                                                                                                                                                                  }
                                                                                                                                                                                   }
                                                                                                                                                                           },
                                                                                                                                                                     'result' => 'Success'
                                                                                                                                                                   }
                                                                                                                                                        }
                                                                                                                                                },
                                                                                                                                          'result' => 'Success'
                                                                                                                                        }
                                                                                                                                },
                                                                                                                          'result' => 'Success'
                                                                                                                        }
                                                                                                                },
                                                                                                          'result' => 'Failure'
                                                                                                        }
                                                                                                },
                                                                                          'result' => 'Failure'
                                                                                        }
                                                                                },
                                                                          'result' => 'Failure'
                                                                        }
                                                                },
                                                          'result' => 'Failure'
                                                        }
                                                },
                                          'result' => 'Failure'
                                        }
                                },
                          'result' => 'Failure'
                        },
                  'culture-info' => {
                                    'current-culture' => 'en-US',
                                    'current-uiculture' => 'en-US'
                                  },
                  'errors' => '1',
                  'time' => '17:43:59',
                  'date' => '2015-01-12',
                  'not-run' => '4',
                  'name' => 'App.exe',
                  'ignored' => '4',
                  'total' => '573',
                  'skipped' => '0',
                  'environment' => {
                                   'user-domain' => 'domain',
                                   'nunit-version' => '2.6.3.13283',
                                   'os-version' => 'Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0',
                                   'cwd' => '',
                                   'user' => 'me',
                                   'platform' => 'Win32NT',
                                   'clr-version' => '4.0.30319.34014',
                                   'machine-name' => ''
                                 },
                  'inconclusive' => '2',
                  'invalid' => '0'
                }
        };
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) SO is not a write-some-code-for-me site. You'll have to try for yourself and when you're stuck somewhere then state your problem here and you'll get help.

Comment: I think you should be more concrete. In what way you want to get elements? Only its name and its attributes, its position (depth) in the tree or what? Do you want to print, iterate over them, in any order?

Comment: I just want to print all <TC> attibute key and values.

name =somename,success = True,asserts = 0,time= 0.005,executed=True,result=Success

Comment: Are you sure you mean `TC`? There are no TC elements in this XML.

Comment: I have removed a part from hash output as SO did not allow me to, as it was too long. You can find the TC elements in the actual XML

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use [XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~grantm/XML-Simple-2.20/lib/XML/Simple.pm). It's a misnomer. It's not simple at all, it's for simple XML.

> The use of this module in new code is discouraged.

Try [XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/XML-Twig-3.48/Twig.pm) instead.

Part of your problem is that simply - you have a deep nested XML structure. There's a limited number of ways to 'display' that.

But pretty much what *every* XML parser does is - convert your XML to a perl datastructure - which is typically a hash. But what it'll also usually do, is let you *print* the structure back into 'proper' XML.

So for a simple reformat task, XML::Twig will let you:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

sub handle_tc {
    my ( $twig, $tc ) = @_;   
    foreach my $attr ( keys %{ $tc -> atts() } ) {
        print "$attr = ".$tc->att($attr)."\n";
    }
    print "\n"; 
}

my $twig_parser = XML::Twig->new(
    pretty_print  => 'indented',
    twig_handlers => { 'TC' => \&handle_tc },
)->parsefile('F:\mydump.log');


print "\n\nWhole XML pretty_print\n\n"; 
$twig_parser->print;
```

This will - as it goes - print every 'name' attribute of a 'TS' element. Each time a `TS` element is encountered by the parser, the handler is called with that XML subset.

And for the sake of comparison, `$twig_parser -> print` which will reformat based on the 'pretty_print' option, and output. (But given your source XML, probably won't change it much).

Comment: The value of `pretty_print` should be between quotes. The OP wants to extract (based on comments) the `TC` element, not `TS`. And you could use something like `for $e (keys %{$_->atts}) { printf "%s=%s\n", $e, $_->atts->{$e}; }` to print at same time the keys and values, as the OP asked.

Comment: Good call on listing all the attributes - I'd gone for the simple option :).

Comment: Thank you gentlemen! I will try out these and update here.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments, if you just want the TC nodes, you can parse the XML file and iterate over the nodes, extracting/printing the information you want if the node is labelled TC.

Alternatively, you could use a regular expression while reading the file to capture TC nodes and then extract the information you want.

What you get by using XML Parsers is what you dumped, and this is what you would expect to get, so I'm not sure what exactly you expected. A flatter structure with no nesting?